# Insert a long text into a table

Tags: tables

How Can I insert this table ?

[image]

Here is MWE :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
 \textbf{Problématique}  &  \textbf{Objectif}  &    \textbf{Résultat}  \\
\hline
$P_{\alpha}$  & Éclairer la décision par le choix d'un sous ensemble aussi restreint que possible en vue d'un choix final d'une seule
action, ce sous ensemble contenant des "meilleures" actions (optimums) ou à défaut, des actions "satisfaisantes". 
& Un choix ou une procédure de sélection \\
\hline
$P_{\beta}$ & Éclairer la décision par un tri résultant d'une affectation de chaque action à une catégorie, les catégories étant définies a
priori en fonction de normes ayant trait à la suite à donner aux actions qu'elles sont destinées à recevoir.
 & Un tri ou une procédure d'affectation \\
\hline
$P_{\gamma}$ & Éclairer la décision par un rangement obtenu en regroupant tout ou partie (les "plus satisfaisantes") des actions en classes
d'équivalence, ces classes étant ordonnées, de façon complète ou partielle, conformément au préférences. 
&   Un rangement ou une procédure de classement \\
\hline
$P_{\delta}$ & Éclairer la décision par une description, dans un langage approprié, des actions et de leurs conséquences. 
& Une description ou une procédure cognitive
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Les quatre problématiques de référence en ADMC}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Try `p{.3\linewidth}`  instead of the `c` or `r`. You might also want to checkout `m` instead of `p`.

Comment: A different alternative might be tabularx and an X column for the second column.

Answer (score 3):

off-topic:

- don't use positioning options `[H]`, it can make problems. better is to use `[htb]`
- tables's captions are usual on the top of table

on-topic (maybe you liked):

- with use of the packages `cellspace` and `tabularx` you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}SX|
                                >{\hsize=0.3\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
 \textbf{Problématique}  &  \hfil\textbf{Objectif}  &    \textbf{Résultat}  \\
\hline
$P_{\alpha}$  
    & Éclairer la décision par le choix d'un sous ensemble aussi restreint que possible en vue d'un choix final d'une seule action, ce sous ensemble contenant des "meilleures" actions (optimums) ou à défaut, des actions "satisfaisantes".
        & Un choix ou une procédure de sélection        \\
\hline
$P_{\beta}$ 
    & Éclairer la décision par un tri résultant d'une affectation de chaque action à une catégorie, les catégories étant définies a priori en fonction de normes ayant trait à la suite à donner aux actions qu'elles sont destinées à recevoir.
        & Un tri ou une procédure d'affectation         \\
\hline
$P_{\gamma}$ 
    & Éclairer la décision par un rangement obtenu en regroupant tout ou partie (les "plus satisfaisantes") des actions en classes
d'équivalence, ces classes étant ordonnées, de façon complète ou partielle, conformément au préférences.
    &   Un rangement ou une procédure de classement     \\
\hline
$P_{\delta}$ 
    & Éclairer la décision par une description, dans un langage approprié, des actions et de leurs conséquences.
        & Une description ou une procédure cognitive    \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Les quatre problématiques de référence en ADMC}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

or with the package `booktabs` and without ˛cellspace` and vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X
                               >{\hsize=0.3\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
 \textbf{Problématique}  &  \hfil\textbf{Objectif}  &    \textbf{Résultat}  \\
    \midrule
$P_{\alpha}$  
    & Éclairer la décision par le choix d'un sous ensemble aussi restreint que possible en vue d'un choix final d'une seule action, ce sous ensemble contenant des "meilleures" actions (optimums) ou à défaut, des actions "satisfaisantes".
        & Un choix ou une procédure de sélection        \\
\addlinespace
$P_{\beta}$ 
    & Éclairer la décision par un tri résultant d'une affectation de chaque action à une catégorie, les catégories étant définies a priori en fonction de normes ayant trait à la suite à donner aux actions qu'elles sont destinées à recevoir.
        & Un tri ou une procédure d'affectation         \\    \addlinespace
\addlinespace
$P_{\gamma}$ 
    & Éclairer la décision par un rangement obtenu en regroupant tout ou partie (les "plus satisfaisantes") des actions en classes
d'équivalence, ces classes étant ordonnées, de façon complète ou partielle, conformément au préférences.
    &   Un rangement ou une procédure de classement     \\
\addlinespace
$P_{\delta}$ 
    & Éclairer la décision par une description, dans un langage approprié, des actions et de leurs conséquences.
        & Une description ou une procédure cognitive    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Les quatre problématiques de référence en ADMC}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zako I copied your the first code, I couldn't compile. I got the massage as this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/190oX8yhh5J3s8zXtV3gjI4U-dxWb-wbv/view

Comment: indeed. the firs example has error in line `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[2]{m{#1}}`  it should be `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`. now corrected, tested and now work. sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

After some researches I finally got the solution :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm}|m{80mm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Problématique}    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{80mm}|}{\textbf{Objectif}}   & \textbf{Résultat} \\
\hline
\textbf{$P_{\alpha}$} & Éclairer la décision par le choix d'un sous ensemble aussi restreint que possible en vue d'un choix final d'une seule
action, ce sous ensemble contenant des "meilleures" actions (optimums) ou à défaut, des actions "satisfaisantes". & Un choix ou une procédure de
sélection \\
\hline
\textbf{$P_{\beta}$} & Éclairer la décision par un tri résultant d'une affectation de chaque action à une catégorie, les catégories étant définies a
priori en fonction de normes ayant trait à la suite à donner aux actions qu'elles sont destinées à recevoir. & Un tri ou une procédure 
d'affectation \\
\hline
\textbf{$P_{\gamma}$} & Éclairer la décision par un rangement obtenu en regroupant tout ou partie (les "plus satisfaisantes") des actions en classes
d'équivalence, ces classes étant ordonnées, de façon complète ou partielle, conformément au préférences. &  Un rangement ou une procédure de
classement \\
\hline
\textbf{$P_{\delta}$} & Éclairer la décision par une description, dans un langage approprié, des actions et de leurs conséquences. & Une description
ou une procédure cognitive \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Les quatre problématiques de référence en ADMC}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

The result :

[image]